# Python crawling from main sites' urls and clean tags save to files with www and urls directly

Tags: python

```
import urllib2
import urllib
from lxml.html import fromstring
from lxml.html.clean import Cleaner
from formatter import NullFormatter
import cookielib
import urllib,time
import urlparse
import datetime
import new
from htmllib import HTMLParser
from lxml.html import fromstring
from lxml.html.clean import Cleaner
import urllib2
import sys,popen2,os
import urlparse

def tagclean(url,Data=None):    
    html = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
    doc = fromstring(html)
    tags = ['h1','h2','h3','h4','h5','h6', 'div', 'span', 'img', 'area', 'map']
    args = {'meta':False, 'safe_attrs_only':False, 'page_structure':False,
            'scripts':True, 'style':True, 'links':True, 'remove_tags':tags}
    cleaner = Cleaner(**args)

    path = '/html/body'
    body = doc.xpath(path)[0]
    return cleaner.clean_html(body).text_content().encode('ascii', 'ignore')

def writetofile(text,filename):
    writefile = open(""+filename+"", "a")
    writefile.write(str(text))
    writefile.close()

if __name__=="__main__":    
    url = raw_input("Enter url:")
    spliturl = url.split("http://")[1].replace(".","_")
    metin=str(tagclean(url))
    writetofile(text,spliturl+".txt")
```

And under my code url scanner:

```
def scanurl(url):   
    print "saving: ",url,datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    tmp=urllib.urlretrieve(url)
    print "saving finished",datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    parser= HTMLParser(NullFormatter( ))
    parser.feed( open(tmp[0]).read( ) )
    urls=[]
    for a in parser.anchorlist:
        urls.append(urlparse.urljoin( url, a ))
return urls
```

I want to combine tagcleaner with this...

Comment: Please take some effort into formulating a question. What issues did you run in to? What did you try? Why didn't it work? Which problem do you want to address? What are some examples of data you are trying to work with?

Comment: i'm only working to combine the clean code with url parser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going on a wild guess here since I don't really know what you are trying to achieve, but don't you mean to replace

```
parser.feed( open(tmp[0]).read( ) )
```

with

```
parser.feed( tagclean(url) )
```

If not, you really need to elaborate your question.

Comment: i want to Python crawling from main sites' urls and clean tags save to urls from main site with their tagcleaned source codes